# Displaying sqrt when returning a function

Tags: python, sqrt, math.sqrt

I am just learning to code so i decided to make a project for myself making a function that finds the zero of a parabola. I think the issue i am having is actually printing out the `sqrt`.

This is the error I receive:

```
File "C:/Users/someb/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Quadratic Formula Solver revised.py", line 10, in find_zero
    return float(-b) + "+-" + float(math.sqrt(discriminant)) + "/" + float(2 * a)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

This is my like fifth revision of the code trying different ways, this originally was supposed to display the two different answers.

```
#Real Zero Finder QUadratic Formula
import math
def find_zero(a,b,c):
    discriminant = (b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)
    if discriminant < 0 :
        return "No real Zeros"
    elif discriminant == 0 :
        return "Vertex is the Zero"
    else:
        #This is where the error is taking place
        return float(-b) + "+-" + float(math.sqrt(discriminant)) + "/" + float(2 * a)

def disc(a,b,c):
    return math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't add a number and a string together. When you call `float`, you're turning the argument into a number, and trying to add it to a string. You can't do that.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because Python doesn't know how to add a string to a float.  You know you're trying to do concatenate the float to the string, but Python doesn't.

The simplest way to print multiple things in Python 3.6+ is to use formatted string literals (f-strings): https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings
You put a `f` before your string and then put what you want to appear in the string inside curly braces `{ }`.

```
return f'{-b} +- {math.sqrt(discriminant)} / {2 * a}'
```

Comment: Starting with python >= 3.6. f-strings are great!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you can't add strings and floats. Since you appear to be outputing a message, I'd prefer to fix this by converting the floats to strings, then the '+' will concatenate those strings. This returns a single string, which may be more useful that returning several values.

```
return str(-b) + " +- " + str(math.sqrt(discriminant)) + " / " + str(2 * a)
```

I also scrapped the float() conversions... I don't think they do anything here.

Answer (score -2):

Problem is here in return:

```
return float(-b) + "+-" + float(math.sqrt(discriminant)) + "/" + float(2 * a)
```

you're trying to connect `float` to a `String`, instead of plus, use commas:

```
return float(-b), " +- ", float(math.sqrt(discriminant)), " / ", float(2 * a)
```